# Is there a python package similar to OpenCV / CV2 that could be used to measure a large object on a scale?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My assignment is to measure images of biological specimens resting on a 2-D scale. An [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDwM4.jpg) of such an image is shown here.

I've drawn as much as possible from an article from PyImageSearch: https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

In the article, the author explores using the CV2 package from OpenCV to measure a number of simple objects by comparing to a reference object of known dimensions. In a sense, my assignment is both simpler (it's resting on top of the scale), and more difficult (the shapes are much more complex).

Essentially, I want to look for ways to locate the 1 cm x 1 cm "blocks" on the scale background and use them to obtain a measurement for the specimen. Even if the measurement is not perfect because of 3D, I could then apply a training-testing algorithm to amend my assessment.

What I'm asking is, is there an easy way to identify an unobstructed 1x1 block on the scale and assign it as the reference object? And is there a reliable way to take the measurement, presumably using the greyscale color differential, of the large specimen? Thanks.

Comment: Threshold on green to get multiple squares using cv2.inRange(). Get their contours. Then get the rotated bounding box (cv2.minAreaRect). Measure a few of these squares for their area (and/or dimensions). Then threshold your object (use morphology to fill out if needed). Then get the area of the objects (number of white pixels) using Numpy count_nonzero(). Then compare the area of your object with that of the average square.

Comment: don't overcomplicate this. just pick (click on) some points manually. then you have a reference in pixels, and you can enter how far those points are apart in reality. if you want to be fancy, do it for the four extreme corner points of the mat and now you can do a homography. -- make sure the camera is mounted rigidly. then you only have to click on those points once. -- keep the entire specimen "on" the green mat. that'll make image processing simpler... assuming you have no specimens that are greenish.

Comment: for the "calibration", you can use whatever, even a sheet of paper. for measuring, I'd recommend something with as strong a contrast as possible, such as a completely black tabletop.

Comment: here's the result of a homography, picking the four corners, and rendering this as 100 pixels per inch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzSe4.jpg -- I'd recommend putting the camera far away from the plane of measurement, to minimize the effect of the specimen not being _in plane_ but a couple inches thick/above it. or calculate with that fact instead. or put that calibration pattern (sheet of paper) a couple inches off the table., roughly bisecting an imaginary specimen.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I appreciate your assistance. Unfortunately, the circumstance here is that these specimens are collected from local fishermen. The marine lab had to bend over backwards to compel them to even take photos (including lobbying for legal requirements to do so). The result of this is that the photos themselves cannot be manipulated in the ways that would be most convenient for us. They are not going to be uniform in terms of the specimen's orientation, the distance from the camera, or the position of the scale. Most of these are slightly different in every photo.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Do you think I could still create a homography on a set of images based on some sort of algorithm that automatically finds the corners?

Comment: (1) sure (2) put no hopes into "automatic". maybe. probably not worth the effort to automate. you'll just need a way for "data entry", i.e. clicking points and such. if you've got a good programmer, they could _make_ a GUI for that, even from just OpenCV. or you find a program for image annotation (for machine learning, but ignore that) which lets you define *polygons*. for the homography, you make a 4-corner polygon. for the specimen, a general polygon. I've heard of "cvat" ("cv annotation tool") but have no idea how much bother that is to set up.